# What song plays at 19:10 in episode 28?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the name of the song that starts at 19:10 in episode 28 ("Eat Or Be Eaten, Panic In The Forest") of normal Naruto?

Answer (score 1):

If the time you're referring to is from an episode not including the opening, that song starts when Naruto stops Orochimaru when he is about to attack Sasuke. It's [Naruto Main Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daPo6q4FXDw), from the first OST of Naruto.